# Is there any legal guideline to use facebook login and reward virtual coins

Tags: facebook-login

I am giving user 500 virtual coins to login using Facebook.
Is there any legal guideline to use Facebook login for reward virtual currency?

I have gone through below link but I don't find anything for rewarding.
https://developers.facebook.com/policy#login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 4.5 **Only incentivize a person to log into your app**, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.

I would say it´s fine to reward users for login, the rules are pretty clear about that. Although, I am not a lawyer and of course I cannot guarantee that it´s allowed, of course.

Comment: Thanks, Luschn. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5 is my answer.